# How can I create html css table like this excel table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the example of an excel table [image: Excel table image]

Here is my table

[image: My table HTML CSS boostrap]

How can I create like excel table of these 3 rows in "APRIL 2022 PODACI O RADU" in the HTML table

Here is my code right now I use bootstrap 5, I want to change 'Redovan rad', 'Prekovremeni rad' and 'Prekovremeni rad 100%' to be like in excel table image

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Broj kartice</th>
        <th>Ime i Prezime</th>
        <th>Za Mesec</th>
        <th>Redovan rad</th>
        <th>Prekovremeni rad 50%</th>
        <th>Prekovremeni rad 100%</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>21</th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th>23</th>
        <th>24</th>
        <th>25</th>
        <th>26</th>
        <th>27</th>
        <th>28</th>
        <th>29</th>
        <th>30</th>
        <th>31</th>
        <th>Redovan rad ukupno sati</th>
        <th>Prekovremeni rad 50% ukupno sati</th>
        <th>Prekovremeni rad 100% ukupno sati</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>213445</td>
        <td>Marko Markovic</td>
        <td>April</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So what you want is to change width of x first elements and x last ? If yes, is it always 6 at the start and 3 at the end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any better way for this solution

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Generate CSV For Your Work</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        th {
            text-align:center;
        }
        tbody td {
            text-align: center; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }

        td span {
            display:block;
            padding:3px;
            margin: 3px 0
        }

        td .hour_style {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        thead tr {
            line-height:15px;
        }

        thead th { 
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .topics th { line-height: 14px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 my-5">

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Broj kartice</th>
                                <th>Ime i Prezime</th>
                                <th>Za Mesec</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>1</th>
                                <th>2</th>
                                <th>3</th>
                                <th>4</th>
                                <th>5</th>
                                <th>6</th>
                                <th>7</th>
                                <th>8</th>
                                <th>9</th>
                                <th>10</th>
                                <th>11</th>
                                <th>12</th>
                                <th>13</th>
                                <th>14</th>
                                <th>15</th>
                                <th>16</th>
                                <th>17</th>
                                <th>18</th>
                                <th>19</th>
                                <th>20</th>
                                <th>21</th>
                                <th>22</th>
                                <th>23</th>
                                <th>24</th>
                                <th>25</th>
                                <th>26</th>
                                <th>27</th>
                                <th>28</th>
                                <th>29</th>
                                <th>30</th>
                                <th>31</th>
                                <th>Redovan rad ukupno sati</th>
                                <th>Prekovremeni rad 50% ukupno sati</th>
                                <th>Prekovremeni rad 100% ukupno sati</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>213445</td>
                                <td>Marko Markovic</td>
                                <td>April</td>

                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <span>Redovan Rad</span>
                                    <span>Prekovremeni + 50%</span>
                                    <span>Prekovremeni + 100% </span>
                                </td>

                                <td>  
                                    <span class="hour_style">5</span> 
                                    <span class="hour_style">2</span> 
                                    <span class="hour_style">3</span>   
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```